# Formulating Image Outline Programmatically (Preferrably C#/C++ coding, or pseudo coding)

Tags: c#, c++, math, graphics

I would just like to ask for assistance to anyone on the logic, and much better sample code of formulating an image's outline.

To make it clearer, I'm talking about a transparent image. Say, I have a PNG image with a polygon shape in the middle, or much better a top view of an island. Now, I would like to trace the outlines and set a color on it. Like the Effect 'Stroke' in Adobe Photoshop.

I have accomplished that far, I've created a program that would trace the outlines. But my problem is, it's linear scanning. From left to right, then down, then left to right again. I'm sure you get the idea. I wanted the tracing to be flowing, like you would trace it manually. Like you with Trace a Circle.

The purpose is, for it to be used as a trigger area for hovering accurately a polygon. And also my problem is if there's two island for example.

I hope my query is clear. Any suggestions, samples are appreciated. But much better if it's in a c# code form or pseudo code with some explanations.

Thanks a lot in advance.

--
Addition:

Also, I would like (I guess I've forgotten to mention) to record the coordinates of the stroke in a sequential manner. So I could manipulate them later on. That is why I wanted to make the outlining logic in a flow manner. That is the algorithm i'm looking for specifically. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you want an image (raster) result, or geometrical (vector) data? "The purpose is, for it to be used as a trigger area for hovering accurately a polygon" - this doesn't clear anything up.  I can think of several things you could mean, but none of them stand out as specifically what you're trying to do.  If it isn't important, maybe you should remove it from the question.  If it is, maybe you should expand on it.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a general edge detection algorithm. For example, [Sobel edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). However, it's not optimized for clean, antialiased, two-color images like the example below, so it produces a somewhat rough result. To better preserve the antialiasing, and get a smooth result, I suggest the following algorithm:

```
Image blurredImg = gaussianBlur(sourceImg, blurRadius = desiredOutlineWidth);
const float sharpnessCoef = 0.1; // value may need tuning or may need to
                                 // depend on the blur radius
Image dilatedImg = from blurredImg, map all pixels with
                   brightness > sharpnessCoef to white and
                   multiply the rest by 1 / sharpnessCoef
Image smoothResult = subtract sourceImg from dilatedImg
```

Example:

[image: edge detection]

Comment: +1 since this is really easy to implement, and will give good results very quickly.  I'm not 100% sure it will solve his final problem, but it is what he asked for at the top of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using image processing techniques, like this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Canny_Edge_Detection.aspx