# python library to find outline of image

Tags: python, image

I am working with Python and PyQt4. I am looking a library with which I can find the outline path of an image (bitmap). With "outline path" I mean a polygon, which separates filled (non-transparent) pixels in the middle of the image from transparent pixels surrounding them.

I can not find anything via google, which kind of makes me wonder if I am using the correct search terms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV has a function called [FindContours](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) which does what I want.

Answer (score 2):

There are [similar questions here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507112/formulating-image-outline-programmatically-preferrably-c-c-coding-or-pseudo) which may be of use... ? Essentially you're trying to do [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection); try searching for that..

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Unfortunately all I can find searching for edge-detection is algorithm transforming the image to an edge-image, which is not what I want.