# How to find the shape of an object in an image using python

Tags: python, image

I want to know how to find the shape of an object in the image and store it in a variable for further use. For instance,

[image]

And I want to extract only the shape, something like this(I manipulated the image in photoshop),

[image]

I just need the outline of the image, and I want to save it on the disk.I haven't tried so far, and I'm using python 2.7

Any suggestion are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I haven't tried so far` come back when you have

Comment: You can try this using ImageMagic - http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#color-in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't recommend grayscale for your image.  You appear to be interested in *red* flower versus *green* background.  A simple and clear way to make that distinction in your image to identify with the flower any pixels whose red value is higher than its green value.

```
import cv2
from numpy import array    
img = cv2.imread('flower.jpg')
img2 = array( 200  * (img[:,:,2] > img[:,:, 1]), dtype='uint8')
```

`img2` clearly shows the shape of the flower.  To get the edges only, you can use a canny edge detector:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img2, 70, 50)
cv2.imwrite('edges.png', edges)
```

The resulting file, `edges.png`, looks like:

[image]

The next step, if you want, is to extract coordinates of the edges.  This can be done with:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Documentation on `cv2.canny` and `cv2.findContours` can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#canny) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours), respectively.

#### More:  What happens if you use grayscale:

```
img = cv2.imread('flower.jpg', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
gray1 = cv2.Canny(img, 70, 50)
cv2.imwrite('gray1.png', gray1)
```

The resulting image is:

[image]

The grayscale approach shows a lot of the internal structure of the flower.  Whether that is good or bad depends on your objectives.

Comment: It seems to be very easy, but is it holds good for every image or only for the red vs green image?

Comment: @varsha_holla In computer vision, _there are no truly general solutions_.  In this case, if you are looking for a red flower on a green background, it would be quite possible for the red and green to have the same grayscale value, making grayscale useless, but using red-vs-green can give you a clear image.  On the other hand, if you were looking for a green tree against a blue sky, then green-vs-blue makes more sense.  If you are looking at a bland cityscape on a cloudy day, there may be no useful colors at all.  You have to do it case by case.

Comment: @varsha_holla To illustrate the issues, I just added the results if grayscale is used: the output shows much of the internal structure of the flower.  If you are interested in the internal structure, then that is a good thing.  If you are not, then it is not.

Comment: I found this response very helpful and instructive. I'd just like to add that in my own brief experience, `findContours` works better with something like `img2` (above), rather than `edges`.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't tried anything yet, I suggest you to try first :)

Here are some pointers:

- convert the image to greyscale
- hold the greyscale image in a numpy array
- make an histogram to count levels in the image
- apply a threshold, to remove background
- you may try adaptive threshold (look on the web)
- apply an edge-detection algorithm (like Canny)
- use morphological mathematics like erosion, dilation to get a better result

Some useful information here: http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/image_processing/

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of Tutorials and question may be useful for You i think
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/07/building-pokedex-python-indexing-sprites-using-shape-descriptors-step-3-6/

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323047/python-library-to-find-outline-of-image),[link2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection),[link3](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors%20python&oq=structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors%20python&aqs=chrome..69i57.3064j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8),[link4](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html),[link 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507112/formulating-image-outline-programmatically-preferrably-c-c-coding-or-pseudo)