# Overlaying path of transperent background png

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need a way to find the overlaying path of a transparent background PNG or GIF (path of the border of filled pixels).

I need this path in vector format (XAML especially).

Any ideas?

Comment: No. I dont even know where should I start.

Comment: First you need some sort of Edge Detection, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507112/formulating-image-outline-programmatically-preferrably-c-c-coding-or-pseudo) is a good start. This is propably the hardest part, now the information you have for the edges needs to be transformed to a wpf Path or Geometry object. Of course this whole subject is pretty complex and you won't get an complete out of the box solution here, but maybe my comment contains enough informations to google what you need.

Comment: @dowhilefor thanx a lot man. If you answer by this I will hit the right answer button :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't supposed as an answer, but seems enough for the OP.

First you need some sort of Edge Detection, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507112/formulating-image-outline-programmatically-preferrably-c-c-coding-or-pseudo) is a good start. This is propably the hardest part, now the information you have for the edges needs to be transformed to a wpf Path or Geometry object. Of course this whole subject is pretty complex and you won't get an complete out of the box solution here, but maybe my comment contains enough informations to google what you need.

I also remembered, that farseer, a physic engine for C#/XNA has a function to create a physic object from a sprite. Maybe on the site or in the code you can find some ideas how to solve it aswell.